# How i can save the content of a listbox into a MS Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have this list box with 2 columns and I need to have a button to save all the information from the list box into my Microsoft Access database. I can not find any tutorials this information about how I can do that.

I have this listbox :

```
private void insertdatainListBox(string movingaction)
{
        var timeaction = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(movingaction + "\t\t" + timeaction);
}
```

and this database

```
     private void saveindb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"data source =ElevatorLog.accdb";
            string dbcommand = "insert into [Elevator] ([MovingAction],[TimeAction]) values (@movingaction, @timeaction)";
            OleDbConnection conn_db = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection);
            OleDbCommand comm_insert = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn_db);

            foreach (string movingaction in listBox1.Items)
            {

                comm_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movingaction", movingaction);

                conn_db.Open();
                comm_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn_db.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Records inserted succesfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!!!");
        }
    }
```

I make this button and i get the error : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: What kind of results are you getting with the code you have? Does it throw an error? Or does it complete with no error,  but the data does not appear in the database?

Comment: I do not have any errors . I have buttons who save data in the listbox. But i need an button to save the data from the boxlist into the database. But i don t know how to code that button

Comment: This how my list box is looking https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gRDd.png

Comment: Is this code you are showing trying to put data into the Access database? Or take it out? Your post says *"save all the information from the list box into my Microsoft Access database"* but the code sure does look like you are trying to extract data and show it on the screen. I'm confused.

Comment: Yes you are right i put the display button code here. Sorry for this misunderstood.What i need is  a new  button to save the data from the list in the database and i don t know how to do this.

Comment: Ok, this code looks better.  So.. same question again? Does it throw an error? Or does it complete with no error, but the data does not appear in the database?  (Also, it looks like you are missing the parameter AddWithValue() for @timeaction)

Comment: Also... have you tried wrapping all of this in a `try catch`? If so, what is the result?

Comment: How many items do you have in the list?  Because that's now many parameters you keep adding.  Either create the query inside the loop or clear the parameter collection.  Where's the timeAction parameter?

Comment: Yes the error is: it is expecting 2  parameters movingaction and timeaction but i don t know how to take both of them from the listbox in this bite of code:                 
             foreach (string movingaction in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    comm_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeaction", timeaction);
                    comm_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movingaction", movingaction);
                    conn_db.Open();
                    comm_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn_db.Close();

Comment: OleDB doesn't do named parameters.  They are in index order only.  That means the have to be added in the same order they appear in the query.  So add movingAction first, then add timeAction.

Comment: even if i change the position of it i have an error timeaction does t exist in the current context

Comment: i can share it with visual studio if you want to see all the code  https://prod.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/join?B26A744F0783540990C6EABE68900FD7AA8C

Comment: Your timeAction that is declared in the insertdatainListBox method is only local to that method.  Also, like I previously stated, you keep adding more than two parameters every time you loop because you don't clear the parameter collection.

Comment: I just want to save both columns from the list box to the database(it has 2 columns as well)

Comment: Does this help https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/winform/c-insert-listbox-items-to-database/